# Rails parse request so I get all query params as one parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-get

I am sending an entire search path as a request parameter.

`...path/?url=https://www.example.com/en/search?s%5Bparam1%5D=value1&s%5Bparam2%5D=value2&s%5Bparam3%5D=value3`

Rails controller interprets this as

`params[:url]` returns `"https://www.example.com/en/search?s[param1]=value1"`

and

`pararms[:s]` returns `"{"s"=>{"param2"=>"value2", "param3"=>"value3"}`

Is there any way I can access the entire request string within `params[:url]`?

Outcome => `params[:url]` will return `"https://www.example.com/en/search?s[param1]=value1&s[param2]=value2&s[param3]=value3"`

Comment: You need to properly escape the url before you send it as a parameter. In ruby you can use `CGI.escape(str)`, in JavaScript you would use `encodeURIComponent(str)`. What you are seeing as actually more of a bug since you are requesting a malformed URL.

Comment: Figured that in the meanwhile. Url needs to be properly encoded before submitting it. Thank you for the answer

Comment: No problem. You can answer the question yourself if you want to help others.

Answer (score 1):

It seemed like the url was not formatted correctly, as you can't have `example.com?url=otherexample.com?a=b&b=c`.

The `url` param has to be encoded before submitted in the request.

Answer (score 0):

You Can send the parameters like this

```
http://www.example.com/en/search?x[]=1&x[]=2&x[]=3
```

and will receive the parameter as an array in the backend

```
arr = params[:x] /// [1,2,3]
```